# Why is GLOB called GLOB? What is the full form of it?

Tags: glob

I am just curious to know why is GLOB called GLOB? I just came to know the reason of why is GREP called GREP because its full form is Global Regular Expression Print, so similarly what is the full form of GLOB? I searched on Google but couldn't find any answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)):

> The glob command, short for global, originates in the earliest versions of Bell Labs' Unix.[1] The command interpreters of the early versions of Unix (1st through 6th Editions, 1969–1975) relied on a separate program to expand wildcard characters in unquoted arguments to a command: /etc/glob. That program performed the expansion and supplied the expanded list of file paths to the command for execution.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't search very well...

> The glob command, short for global, originates in the earliest versions of Bell Labs' Unix.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

Comment: Yeah... Anyway, Thank you!